# Date picker for Calender to Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, datepicker, calendar

Below is a script I found and modified to track events by grabbing event information from our Calendar(s) and populating a spreadsheet (with mild reformatting)  based on a selected date range.

Currently I have to manually change the dates within the script each week to get the events that I need.   I would like to have a date picker pop up when I open a new sheet  and have the selected dates input to the script,  but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function main(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  var header = [["Calendar Address", "Calendar Name", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event Description" ]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,6);
  range.setValues(header);
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
// var mycals is an array of google calendar id's; for gsuite, this is the email address of the user which calendar you will be viewing.
  var mycals = ['9ss30f8ktuvbedmemka1ve8jss@group.calendar.google.com','8nmutqctujaetrnt5kfvi56kuo@group.calendar.google.com','ae1d2v0sqtktc183546u6cenps@group.calendar.google.com','ilr8eqk2l0ua9pr50t5307ivq8@group.calendar.google.com','5qubvv7mj5vjf7h1hhc23515h8@group.calendar.google.com', 'p2a9plkjd3vv9c87kb5kirapqk@group.calendar.google.com', '9ubfnjrb83tiqgi5l1nitaodp0@group.calendar.google.com', 'l6ouqfpktn05hstmokj8jhr1s4@group.calendar.google.com'  ]


for (var j=0;j<mycals.length;j++) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycals[j]);
  // error handling in case you don't have access to any specified calendar
  if (!cal) { continue; }
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("12/30/2019 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("1/3/2020 23:59:59 EST"));
        for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
          var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
          var details=[[events[i].getOriginalCalendarId(),,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getDescription()]];
          var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,6);
          range.setValues(details);
          sheet.getRange(i+2, 5).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm Am/PM");
        }
sheet.sort(1);
}
var lr= sheet.getLastRow();

  for(var k=0+1; k<lr+1;k++){

    var workingCell = sheet.getRange(k,1).getValue();

      if(workingCell == '9ss30f8ktuvbedmemka1ve8jss@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("ATG_Cert");
      }
       else if(workingCell == '8nmutqctujaetrnt5kfvi56kuo@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("Functionality_Test");
         }
       else if(workingCell == 'ae1d2v0sqtktc183546u6cenps@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("Tightness_Test");
         }
       else if(workingCell == 'ilr8eqk2l0ua9pr50t5307ivq8@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("Pre_or_Post_Bury");
          }
       else if(workingCell == '5qubvv7mj5vjf7h1hhc23515h8@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("LLD");
         }
       else if(workingCell == 'p2a9plkjd3vv9c87kb5kirapqk@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("PMI");
         }
       else if(workingCell == '9ubfnjrb83tiqgi5l1nitaodp0@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("Stage_II_DeComm_Test");
         }
       else if(workingCell == 'l6ouqfpktn05hstmokj8jhr1s4@group.calendar.google.com'){
        sheet.getRange(k,2).setValue("Other");

  }
}
  sheet.getRange(1,1,lr,6).setFontSize(14)  
  sheet.hideColumns(1);
  sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 6);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, lr, 6).setHorizontalAlignment("left")



}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a date-picker on the google apps script editor?

Comment: Yes.  I would like to add to the above script, so that opening a new tab would trigger a date picker and those chosen dates would be the range (line 16) of events to grab.

'var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("12/30/2019 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("1/3/2020 23:59:59 EST"));'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rest of your code works then try this modification:

```
function main(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  var header = [["Calendar Address", "Calendar Name", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event Description" ]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,6);
  range.setValues(header);
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  var mycals = ['9ss30f8ktuvbedmemka1ve8jss@group.calendar.google.com','8nmutqctujaetrnt5kfvi56kuo@group.calendar.google.com','ae1d2v0sqtktc183546u6cenps@group.calendar.google.com','ilr8eqk2l0ua9pr50t5307ivq8@group.calendar.google.com','5qubvv7mj5vjf7h1hhc23515h8@group.calendar.google.com', 'p2a9plkjd3vv9c87kb5kirapqk@group.calendar.google.com', '9ubfnjrb83tiqgi5l1nitaodp0@group.calendar.google.com', 'l6ouqfpktn05hstmokj8jhr1s4@group.calendar.google.com'  ]
  var today=new Date();//added
  var day=today.getDay();//added
  var start=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-day+8);//added 
  var end=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-day+12);//added
  for (var j=0;j<mycals.length;j++) {
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycals[j]);
    // error handling in case you don't have access to any specified calendar
    if (!cal) { continue; }
    var events = cal.getEvents(start,end);
```

It looked like you want to view next weeks events between monday and friday.  If not then make it a bit clearer what you are looking for.

Comment: To Clarify:  This script is intended to generate reports of jobs we've performed and ready for invoicing. The original script works great at pulling the events from the selected range in line 16 and populating the sheet for my billing team:  The only issue is having to open the script editor and changing the dates in line 16 every time I need  a report. 

My goal is that when a new sheet is opened it would trigger a date picker box (menu) so the user could select a date range which would populate the date range in  line 16 of the script without having to open script editor.